# PHP split string containing html tags and split string into array

Tags: php

1. Question

   i have string like this ***$str="a|apple||b|bat||c|cat||d|dog";***

   from the above string i want to create a array dynamically n that newly created array     shud look like this   ***Array
                    (
                      [a] => apple
                      [b] => bat
                      [c] => cat
                      [d] => dog
                    )***
2. Question

   i have html string like this

   ```
               $html_string="<div>Content Div1</div>
                             <div>Content Div2</div>
                             <div>Content Div3</div>";
   ```

how can i get 3rd DIV ,resulting answer should be like this

```
              $ans="<div>Content Div3</div>" ;
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: Only one question *What have you tried so far?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**for the first one**

```
$str = "a|apple||b|bat||c|cat||d|dog";
$new_array = array();

$my_array = explode("||", $str);
$my_array = array_filter($my_array);

foreach ($my_array as $mine) {
  $my = explode("|", $mine);
  $new_array[$my[0]] = $my[1];
}
```

print_r($new_array);

// Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => bat
    [c] => cat
    [d] => dog
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**for second**

$html_string = "<div>Content Div1</div><div>Content Div2</div><div>Content Div3</div>";
$new_arr = explode("</div>", $html_string);
$my_data = $new_arr[2] . '</div>';
print_r($my_data);
```

// Output

```
<div>Content Div3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**First**

```
$str = "a|apple||b|bat||c|cat||d|dog";
$my_array = explode("||", $str);
$finalArr=array();
foreach($my_array as $my_arr)
{
   $myar = explode("|", $my_arr);
   $finalArr[$myar[0]]=$myar[1];
}
print_r($finalArr);
```

**For Second**

```
$html_string="<div>Content Div1</div><div>Content Div2</div><div>Content Div3</div>";
$secondArray = explode('</div>', $html_string);
echo $res = $secondArray[2] . "</div>";
```

Test it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1st Answer:

```
<?php
$str="a|apple||b|bat||c|cat||d|dog";
$parentArray = explode('||', $str);
$finalArray = array();
foreach($parentArray as $parentKey=>$parentValue)
{
    $childArray = explode('|', $parentValue);
    $finalArray[$childArray[0]] = $childArray[1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
?>
```

2nd Answer

```
<?php
$html_string="<div>Content Div1</div>
                          <div>Content Div2</div>
                          <div>Content Div3</div>";
$finalArray = explode('</div>', $html_string);
$resultRequired = $finalArray[2] . "</div>";                     
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**For your first question:**

```
    $tmp_array = explode( '||', $str );
    $str_array = array();

    foreach( $tmp_array as $value ){

        $tmp = explode( '|', $value );
        $str_array[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];

    }
```

**For your second question**

```
    $html_array = array();
    $pattern = '/\<div\>.*\<\/div\>/i';

    if( preg_match_all( $pattern, $html_string, $matches ) ) {
        $html_array = $matches[0];
    }
```

**Which will make:**

```
    <div>Content Div3</div>
```

**Be in $html_array[2] if any matches are found.**